# number of spanning trees in this graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

This is a homework help, it ask us to find the number of spanning trees in this graph.

[image]

I can use "matrix tree theorem" to solve it, but that means I need to compute the determinant of a $ 15\times 15$ matrix, which seems an horror to me.

Is there an easier way to compute?

Comment: Take a look at the matrix you must calculate the determinant of. Does it have any special structure?

Comment: If all you care about is the determinant, http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/ lets you do that for matrices up to 32x32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph has 16 vertices, so any spanning tree will have 15 edges. The graph starts with 20 edges, so we need to remove 5. We have to break each of the four 5-cycles, so by the pigeonhole principle we will take a single edge from three of the 5-cycles and two edges from one of them.

We also have to break the 4-cycle in the middle. If we remove an edge shared by a 5-cycle and the 4-cycle, we must remove another edge from that 5-cycle, otherwise we end up with an interior 7-cycle. Thus in the 5-cycle that we remove two edges from, one of them must be the edge shared with the 4-cycle.

There are four shared edges to choose from. Once we pick that, there are four other edges in that 5-cycle to remove. Once we do that, each of the three remaining 5-cycles has 5 choices for us to delete one edge from.

Thus in total we have $4\cdot 4 \cdot 5^3 = 2000$ spanning trees.

Comment: I got your point, and the reason is reasonable to me, except the " end up with an interior 7-cycle " part, it might not be "7". (however the result and conlusion won't change)